# Why can we set lists but not constants from karate function?

Tags: karate

We need karate.get() when setting a constant from a karate function:
[Why operator '+' inside functions does not modify * def made variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920830/why-operator-inside-functions-does-not-modify-def-made-variables)

Why don't we need this when appending to lists?
The example:

```
Scenario: karate forEach operation on maps
    * def keys = []
    * def vals = []
    * def idxs = []
    * def fun = function(x, y, i){ keys.add(x); vals.add(y); idxs.add(i) }
    * def map = { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6 }
    * eval karate.forEach(map, fun)
    * match keys == ['a', 'b', 'c']
    * match vals == [2, 4, 6]
    * match idxs == [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the example of `keys`. When the function was declared, `keys` was available, and is actually a Java `List` behind the scenes. The function can go on calling the `add()` method without any problems. The reference to `keys` is fixed, and does not change.

But when you try to do the same thing with a primitive type - e.g. a String or Number - you can't change the *reference* to a Karate variable from within the JS engine. You have to ask Karate to set (or get) the latest value.